# reading GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER drops frame rate

Tags: glsl

I'm getting very low frame rate after read back data from a shader storage buffer even if I read the data only once.

this is how I'm binding it:

```
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, posBuf);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, numPoints*4* sizeof(GLfloat),&points[0][0], GL_DYNAMIC_Draw);
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, NULL);
```

and read:

```
GLfloat * temp = new GLfloat[numPoints*4];
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, posBuf);
glGetBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, numPoints* 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), temp);
glBindBuffer( GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0 );
```

after do that once the frame rate drops from 200 to 15.

is there any way to avoid that?

thanks!

Comment: Are you at GL version 4.3 or greater?

Comment: I ask that because my experience is that when I see such a dramatic drop in frame rate it's been because I'm calling something that does not have real hardware support and I'm getting a total software fallback.

Comment: Hi jwlaughton, yes, I'm using 4.3

Comment: Hmm... I'm only at 4.1, so can't test for you.  The way I do it is to create an output buffer for the shaders and attach at texture to it. I then get the data with glGetTexImage().

Comment: Again, I would say that such a dramatic change in frame rate has been because of a lack of hardware support.  Just because you're at 4.3 doesn't mean you have hardware support for everything.  You may still be getting a software fallback.

Comment: interesting! do you have a sample code you can show? thanks luiz

Comment: is there any way I can check which calls are supported? I can see the result on the screen, it looks right and no drop on the frame rate, it drops when I call glGetBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER...

Comment: Code is posted for what it's worth.  The only way I've been able to see what's supported is to get a clue from the drop in frame rate, then investigate the capabilities of the specific GPU.  My experience was in passing doubles to the shaders.  Totally supported in 4.1 and no warnings from anywhere, but the buffer flushes dropped to 15/sec.  Animation was agonizingly slow.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the language, but this is a quick straight up copy of an Objective C method to save a .PNG file.  I'm sure you can glean the salient code.

```
// ****************************************** High Resolution Image With Alpha *********************************************

- (void) saveHiResFileWithAlpha
{    
    // ************************************** Save the Current Viewport Size

    GLint screenViewPort[4];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, screenViewPort);

    // ***************************** Define a Second Output Buffer and Bind it for Writing

    glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, wispSecondOutputBuffer);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, wispSecondOutputBuffer[0]);

    // ******************************* Set the Viewport to the Texture Size and Reshape

    glViewport(0,0,TEXTUREWIDTH, TEXTUREHEIGHT); // Texture is 6000 X 4000
    [self resizeTextureGL]; // Calculate Model View and Projection Matrices

    // ************************************** Create the Output Imgage Texture

    glGenTextures( 1, wispOutputTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, wispOutputTexture[0]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, (GLsizei)TEXTUREWIDTH, (GLsizei)TEXTUREHEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    // ********************************* Attach the Output Texture to the Frame Buffer

    glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, wispOutputTexture[0], 0);

    GLenum DrawBuffers[1] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0};
    glDrawBuffers(1, DrawBuffers);

    // ************************************ Check that the Frame Buffer is Complete

    GLenum frameBufferStatus;

    frameBufferStatus = glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT);

    if(frameBufferStatus != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_EXT) NSLog(@"There is a problem with the output frame buffer");

    // ****************************************** Render to the Texture

    [self runTextureShaders]; // Render the image
    [self runTextureShaders2];

    // ************************************ Reset the Viewport and Frame Buffer

    glViewport(screenViewPort[0],screenViewPort[1],(GLsizei)screenViewPort[2], (GLsizei)screenViewPort[3]);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);

    // ***************************************** Create a bitmap Image Rep

    NSBitmapImageRep* bitmapImageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:(unsigned char **)NULL
                                                                               pixelsWide:(int)TEXTUREWIDTH
                                                                           pixelsHigh:(int)TEXTUREHEIGHT
                                                                        bitsPerSample:(int)8
                                                                      samplesPerPixel:(int)4
                                                                             hasAlpha:(BOOL)YES
                                                                             isPlanar:(BOOL)NO
                                                                       colorSpaceName:(NSString *)NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
                                                                          bytesPerRow:(int)(TEXTUREWIDTH * sizeof(AlphaPixelBytes))
                                                                         bitsPerPixel:(int)0];

    // ******************************* Copy the Texture Data Into the Bitmap Image

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, wispOutputTexture[0]);
    glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bitmapImageRep.bitmapData);

    // ******************************* Multiply the RGB data by the Alpha Component

    AlphaPixelBytes *outputPixel = (AlphaPixelBytes*)[bitmapImageRep bitmapData];
    float floatOutputPixel, floatOutputAlpha;

    for(int i = 0; i < NUMTEXTUREPOINTS; i++)
    {
        floatOutputAlpha = (float)outputPixel[i].alpha / 255.0;

        floatOutputPixel = (float)outputPixel[i].red * floatOutputAlpha;
        outputPixel[i].red = (unsigned char) floatOutputPixel;

        floatOutputPixel = (float)outputPixel[i].green * floatOutputAlpha;
        outputPixel[i].green = (unsigned char) floatOutputPixel;

        floatOutputPixel = (float)outputPixel[i].blue * floatOutputAlpha;
        outputPixel[i].blue = (unsigned char) floatOutputPixel;
    }

    // ********************************************* Set the File Name

    NSMutableString *highResPath = [NSMutableString stringWithString:appController->appDelegate->fileLoaded];

    NSUInteger fileNameLength = highResPath.length;
    NSRange deleteRange;
    deleteRange.location = fileNameLength-3;
    deleteRange.length = 3;
    [highResPath deleteCharactersInRange:deleteRange];
    [highResPath appendString:@"png"];

    // ******************************************* Set the Save Panel

    NSSavePanel *fileSavePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    NSArray* allowedFileTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"png", nil];
    NSURL *saveDirectoryURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:appController->appDelegate->wispUserImageFileDirectory isDirectory:YES];
    [fileSavePanel setAllowedFileTypes:allowedFileTypes];
    [fileSavePanel setTitle:@"Wisp3D File Manager"];
    [fileSavePanel setNameFieldStringValue:highResPath];
    [fileSavePanel setDirectoryURL:saveDirectoryURL];

    // *********************************** Write the Data Out to Disk - No Compression

    NSDictionary *imageProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]
                                                       forKey: NSImageCompressionFactor];
    NSData *outputImageData = [bitmapImageRep representationUsingType: NSPNGFileType properties:imageProps];

    NSUInteger result = [fileSavePanel runModal];

    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
    {
        BOOL saveStatus = NO;
        NSURL *theFile = [fileSavePanel URL];

        // ********************************** Update the Default Directory

        NSString *theNewFileName = [NSString stringWithString:[theFile lastPathComponent]];
        NSUInteger theNewFileLength = theNewFileName.length;
        NSMutableString *theNewPath = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[theFile path]];
        NSUInteger theNewPathLength = theNewPath.length;
        deleteRange.location = theNewPathLength-theNewFileLength-1;
        deleteRange.length = theNewFileLength+1;
        [theNewPath deleteCharactersInRange:deleteRange];

        [appController->appDelegate->wispUserImageFileDirectory setString:theNewPath];

        // ***************************************** Write the File

        saveStatus = [outputImageData writeToURL:theFile atomically:YES];

        NSAlert *fileSavedAlert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
        [fileSavedAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];

        if(saveStatus)
        {
            [fileSavedAlert setMessageText:@"File Save was Successful"];

        }else{
            [fileSavedAlert setMessageText:@"File Save failed"];
        }

        [fileSavedAlert runModal];
    }

    // ******************************************* Cleanup Memory

    glDeleteTextures(1, wispOutputTexture);
    glDeleteFramebuffersEXT(1, wispSecondOutputBuffer);

    return;
}
```

AlphaPixelBytes is defined as:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char alpha;

} AlphaPixelBytes;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to work copying the data to a GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER before use glGetBufferSubData. it works and I have no frame rate drop. I still don't understand why but at least it's working.. thanks a lot for the help!

```
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, _positionBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, _outputBuffer);
glCopyBufferSubData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER,0,0, _vertexCount* 4 * sizeof(GLfloat));
GLfloat temp [_vertexCount][4];
glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, _outputBuffer);
glGetBufferSubData(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, 0, _vertexCount* 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), &temp[0][0]);
glBindBuffer( GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, NULL );
glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, 0);
```